# Timestamp and UTC kind

Tags: c#, date, datetime, timestamp, utc

In my application i receive Time stamp and in c# code I convert into date and pass this date to execute the stored procedure .My application is placed in server machine. But when this date is printed in log i saw the date is receiving in server one day less. Below is my code to convert from time stamp to date,

```
DateTime fromDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
fromDate =fromDate.AddMilliseconds(1430159400000).ToLocalTime();
```

date is : '2015-04-28' But when in server it receive as '2015-04-27'. This i came to know when i print this date in log. What i am doing wrong here!. 
Any suggessions most welcome.

Regards
Sangeetha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well currently you're converting the UTC timestamp to the system-local time - and presumably your server is in a different time zone to you.

I would *strongly* advise you to log the UTC timestamp directly, in UTC. Whatever *reads* your logs can then convert it to a local time in whatever time zone you want, but it's a lot more portable that way:

- you don't need to know what time zone the server was in in order to understand the logs
- you can merge logs from multiple servers trivially
- you don't get any periods of ambiguity where a given local time occurs twice due to a daylight saving transition
- if you plot aspects of the logs on a graph or something similar, you don't end up with bizarre discontinuities again due to daylight saving transitions
- your code behaves the same on your dev machine as on your servers

So, you should:

- Remove the `ToLocalTime` call
- Make sure that however you're logging the timestamp includes `Z` at the end, so that it's clear it's in UTC.
- Make sure that you use the invariant culture for logging, to avoid conversion to non-Gregorian calendars

If you're storing timestamps in the database, I'd recommend storing those in UTC as well. *Some* kinds of date/time values are best stored in local time, but timestamps are more global, representing an instant in time, so UTC is a suitable zone to use for storage.

Answer (score 1):

Since you calculate your `DateTime` based on [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), your `1430159400000` milliseconds (`1430159400` seconds) generates Mon, 27 Apr 2015 18:30:00 UTC.

And since you calculate your local time with [`ToLocalTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, this adds your current time zone offset to this `DateTime`. I strongly suspect your current machine and your server has different time zones and even your current [UTC offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) is equal or more then `+05:30`, that's why your `ToLocalTime` generates a local time that belongs one day after.

Logging a `DateTime` values as `Local` might be ambiguous. You should never do that. You should always store your `DateTime` as `UTC`.

Please read the best practices for that kind of processing;

- [Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices)